# How to configure app.config for Addin class?

Tags: vsto, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have configured the log4net as in the link [Configure log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136199/how-to-create-a-file-in-the-appdata-folder-using-log4net). I have one more project where I have the addin project. The addin project has the same app.config file and I am trying to add the same configure to it. But it is not working. How can I do this?

The addin is designed using VSTO 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the can be problems in vsto when searching for the application.dll.config file. Following the msdn blog the issue was introduced in sp1:

[vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2011/06/14/vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file.aspx)

In the blog the solution is to change the value of the manifest from:

```
Manifest="C:\Program Files\<Path>\WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"
```

to:

```
Manifest="file:///C:\Program Files\<Path>\WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"
```

Comment: should this be changed in the registry? The value for the manifest file is [TARGETDIR]MyExcel.vsto|vstolocal as now. The target folder of my project is Program Files x86.