# How to check whether the log is enabled or disabled?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am trying to check whether the log is enabled or disabled based on the ini file.
But i will have to check this condition every time whether it is enabled or disabled. 
I will have to check this log file is enabled or disabled once and then use it everywhere.
How can I do this?

```
if ("true".Equals(m_objGlobalConfig.SoapLog))
   {
     log.ErrorFormat(se.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, se.StackTrace);
   }
```

Is there anything I can do this customization for the appender ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply disable the log4net initialization based on this parameter, this would prevent log4net from being configured and logging:

During the initialization of your program just do :

```
if ("true".Equals(m_objGlobalConfig.SoapLog))
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo("path/to/file"));
}
```

and then you can log normally

Comment: so we can remove this configuration from the assemblyInfo.cs and put this in the config class?

Comment: If that's where you feel it is adequate yes. The assemblyInfo attribute is one way to configure log4net. I personnaly don't like it but it's a valid an easy way to do it.

Comment: If i remove the initialization of log4net from the assemblyInfo, it is not able to create the log file at all.

Comment: I have done this if ("true".Equals(m_boolSoapLog))
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(m_strGeneralFilePath));
            } and m_strGeneralFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + Config.APPDATA_PATH; But then it is not able to create the file. And the configuration of my appconfig is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136199/how-to-create-a-file-in-the-appdata-folder-using-log4net

Comment: `ConfigureAndWatch` takes the path to the configuration file, not the file you want to log to. The file you want to log to is defined in the configuration file

Comment: I did this  if("true".Equals(m_boolSoapLog))                
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(AppConfigExePath));
            }    and tried to create string AppConfigExePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + APPDATA_PATH; where this points to the Excel.exe.config file. But it dint work again.